# Projection of point from a circle to an arbitrary shape

Tags: matlab, geometry, projection

I want to project the points on a circle to an arbitrary shape. I'm looking for an efficient and computational inexpensive way to do it:

[image: Projection of points]

Comment: Consider adding more details. Which programming language or API are you using? How is the shape given? Is it a sequence of line segments, or parametric (bezier) curve segments? ...

Comment: I am programming in Matlab, the shape is arbitrary and irregular just large that the circle. Actually it's nothing but a bunch of points that are connected togeather